# Very basic syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, css, syntax-highlighting, codemirror, clojurescript

I am looking to make a very basic sytax highlighter. I am looking to get pointed in the right direction. I know there are lots of great projects that do this already (Codemirror, rainbow.js, etc) but I am looking to get help on how these are created, and perhaps a simple example, with Javascript (or clojurescript).

Do these projects make use of parsing the language (using something like PEG.js?) Ideally I would like to parse the language using something like that rather than regexs, but how, once you have defined the language, turn that into a syntax highlighter? Surely on every single keypress you don't re parse the entire tex and apply the formatting? So what's the best way to do something simple? Keep track of current cursor position and only look ahead and behind so many chars? Some sort of state machine?

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you've already looked at the source for code mirror but here's the src reference: https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror
 - I would also like to state that some of these get pretty complex

Comment: A link to the clojure syntax mode: https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/blob/master/mode/clojure/clojure.js

Comment: @Nate Ya, looked at the code and read some of his blog posts. Having a hard time grasping it though so I thought maybe a simple example would be helpful.

Comment: Tip: provide something you don't understand and ask specific questions. You won't get people starting completely free-floating explanations from 5000 miles away.

Answer (score 5):

First off, this is not a good question for StackOverflow. Good questions here are *specific* and about *actual code*.

> Ideally I would like to parse the language using something like that rather than regexs

The first thing you need to do is learn how a language parser works. Do not use regular expressions; regular expressions parse regular languages, and JS is not a regular language.

Language parsers work in two phases. First, lexical analysis, in which the text is broken up into *tokens*, and then the tokens are parsed. This is much easier than parsing the text directly.  JS presents some minor difficulties in that it is lexically ambiguous thanks to the use of `/` to mean division, comments and regular expressions, but you can work around that easily enough.

So the first thing you should do is write a lexer. Then write a parser. In fact, a lexer might be good enough for your needs.

**Keep in mind that you must be able to "correctly" parse JS that is lexically or grammatically incorrect** because when the user is typing, the program is almost certainly not a legal program! This is the hard part of writing a good lexer and parser. Think very carefully about what error recovery heuristics you want, to ensure a good user experience.

> Surely on every single keypress you don't re parse the entire text and apply the formatting?

Obviously it depends on how fast your parser is and how big the file is.

When we were designing the Roslyn syntax highlighter we knew that there could be files with hundreds of thousands of lines in them that were being typed in; we do not re-parse the entire file on every keypress because we could not write a parser that was fast enough.

Instead, we maintain an immutable parse tree and traverse it quickly to determine in which token the keypress happened. We then have a parser that can figure out which parse nodes could possibly have changed, and we re-lex and re-parse only those nodes, and then build a new immutable parse tree out of the unchanged parts of the old tree.

We also only run the syntax colourizer on the portions of the file that are *visible to the user*.

Of course Roslyn also does semantic analysis between keystrokes, but that is a whole other ball of wax.